# Nested Scrollview with paging issue in ios

Tags: ios, nested, scrollview

I have a view hierarchy:-
UIViewController ---> UIScrollview ---> UITableView

Scrollview will only scroll horizontally. In scrollview there are multiple tableviews. When I scroll diagonally, the tableview get scrolled, but I want scrollview to scroll to the next page.

Also when I customize scrollview, I didn't get touchesBegan/Moved/Ended methods called in my uiviewcontroller class.

Comment: Do you have enabled user interaction on your UIViewController's main view? This can be done in your UIViewController subclass with the following line: `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.

Comment: Did you set the scrollviews delegates ?

Comment: yes userinteraction is enabled and also scrollview delegate is set...